# How to jQuery select <td> with only a checkbox in it

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

## The Goal

I want to select `<td>` elements that contain only a checkbox. I want to do this with a single selector (not using chaining or logic outside the selector) so that I can use the selector with jQuery functions like `live` or `delegate`.

The bigger pictures is that I want to listen for a click event on these `<td>`s and pass the click event on to the checkbox, thus creating a larger clicking area. This is important, because the `<tr>` also has a different click event that I don't want to activate when users click and miss the checkbox.

## The specifics

I created a jsfiddle with an example scenario: http://jsfiddle.net/ytA3X/

This is what I started with that is not working. In other words, select any td element that has a checkbox but does not have anything that is not a checkbox.

```
$('td:has(:checkbox):not(:has(:not(:checkbox)))')
=> []
```

`:not(:has(...))` works in my [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ytA3X/).

`:has(:not(...))` works in my [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ytA3X/).

`:not(:has(:not(...)))` always seems to select nothing.

Is there a different way that I can select td elements with only a checkbox, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: So what is your question, you want to select `td` that has only one checkbox element and no other element?

Comment: Any specific reason you aren't using  to increase the clicking area?  Also why are you using a table?  Is the data you're presenting tabular?

Comment: Yes, it's a data table. That's really irrelevant to the question though - you don't need to be the the table police. Even if I were using other elements, I would still have the same problem. What were you saying about increasing the clicking area though? Looks like you left out a word that might have made that comment useful ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about using [`:only-child`](http://api.jquery.com/only-child-selector/):

```
$('td:has(:checkbox:only-child)')...
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wcHJn/)

Comment: +1 Nice, I didn't know jQuert supports this css3 selector. But I wouldn't use if from readability reasons.

Comment: @gdoron: Readability? It says: "select all `td` elements that `have` a `checkbox` as their `only-child`". You can easily read it as a sentence.

Comment: Maybe. I just don't like too many `:` in my selectors. But I loved your answer!

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly the sort of simpler answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it with one selector, it will make your code hard to read and extremely hard to maintain and debug.

```
$('td:has(input[type="checkbox"])').filter(function(){
    return $(this).children().length === 1
});
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ytA3X/2/)

Comment: But then I can't use delegate or live to watch for the click event with a dynamic form.

Comment: @nilbus: What do you mean?  You can still chain `.live` after the call to `.filter`.

Comment: @nilbus add a class to all matching elements  that in the delegation.

Comment: Do you really need to do a `===` check for length property?

Comment: @Vega. You don't **need** to, but `===` is faster than `==`, and always using only this comparison operator can saves you from trouble.

Comment: @gdoron Is it true that `===` is faster than `==`? >> http://jsperf.com/equals-operator <<. I agree that using `===` is better but not in this specific case..

Comment: @gdoron I understand completely and I agree that using `===` is better.. but What I was trying to say is `===` is not faster if the types are the same and it is not THE BEST in this specific case as you had mentioned..  Well to be honest, it is not even a matter of concern to have it discussed so much >.< .. Just trying to explain what I meant.

Comment: @Vega. You're right, in this case, it just a good habit... :) End.

Comment: From the jQuery docs: "Chaining methods is not supported. For example, $("a").find(".offsite, .external").live( ... ); is not valid and does not work as expected." Unless filter is special, I'm pretty sure that doesn't work.

Comment: @nilbus. What jQuery version are you using? why do you still using the deprecated `live` function?

Comment: @ the app is using 1.4.4 where .on isn't available yet. I hesitate to upgrade until I have time to test thoroughly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`only-child` selector](http://api.jquery.com/only-child-selector/):

```
$('td:has(:checkbox:only-child)')
```

[Here it is](http://jsfiddle.net/FjquT/) in use with your markup.

Comment: +1 You were 44 seconds slower, but you still deserve some points for thinking about `:only-child`.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly the sort of simpler answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `.not` instead and split it into two separate selectors:

http://jsfiddle.net/ytA3X/1/

Comment: This will work with two checkboxes as well, Not sure this is the output he wants.